# How to format HD 1TB in more than three gpt partitions?

Tags: partitioning, gpt

How to format HD 1TB in more than three gpt partitions without any operarations system.
At least 7 partitions in gpt 
There is a tutorial to do gpt partitions?
1 for Windows 10 and the others that are need for got style partitions. 
2 for data, backup
3 for Ubuntu.
4 for home in separate partition.
5 for backup or data.

Comment: Windows wants more than one. Often best just to install Windows so it can create all the partitions it expects, then install Ubuntu which now only needs / (root) as ext4 and will reuse the FAT32 formatted partition as the ESP. No need or swap either as new installs use swap partition. Having /home separate is also a good idea. Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Ubuntu:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI How you boot installer  UEFI or BIOS is how it installs.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't need a /home partition, so why do you need one?

Comment: Windows will use the entire HD, I need to leave at least 500GB free for Ubuntu, home, data backup.

Comment: I like home in separate partition

Comment: by the way, my motherboard doesn't has a choose disable security boot.

Comment: If your BIOS doesn't have an option to disable secure boot, then perhaps there is no way to enable secure boot which means that is one less thing to worry about.